# Toggle-collapse menu always open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when I click on button, toggle open menù but when I click the second time menu doesn't close... any idea? sorry , it is my first time on this site!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top gradient" role="navigation" >
  <div class="navbar-header" >
    <!-- Navbar visualizzata su dispositivi mobili-->
     <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#prova" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
      <span class="sr-only" >Menu di navigazione</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>

     <!-- Navbar-brand visualizzata in alto a sinistra-->
     <!-- Indica la sezione del "titolo". href indica il link sul titolo. Color fa               riferimento al titolo. -->
     <a class="navbar-brand gradient text-navbar" href="index.html">Annotaria
     <!--Icona medicina -->
     <img src="http://www.notizieprovita.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/farmacisti_obiezione-di-coscienza_pillola-del-giorno-dopo.jpg" height="100%"/></a>
     </div> <!--Chiuso il div della navbar-header -->



     <div class="nav navbar-collapse collapse  gradient" id="prova" >
     <ul class=" nav navbar-nav" >
     <!--About sessione. data-target fa fronte a cosa caricheremo una volta attivato il modale. -->
        <li><a data-target="#about" data-toggle="modal" role="button" href="#" class="text-navbar">About</a></li>
        <!--Annotazioni non salvate navbar -->
        <li><a id="temp_annot_button" data-target="#temp_annot" data-toggle="modal" role="button" class="text-navbar hide">Annotazioni non salvate</a></li>
        <!--Crea Annotazioni navbar -->
        <li><a id="create_ranged_annot_button" onclick='lightText()' data-target="#doc_annot" data-toggle="modal" role="button" class="text-navbar  hide">Crea annotazioni</a></li>
        <!--Annotator Mode -->
        <li><a id="annotatorPanel" data-toggle="modal" onclick="togliModale()" data-target="#loginModal" role="button" class="text-navbar">Annotator Mode</a></li>
        <!--Help-->
        <li><a data-target="#help" data-toggle="modal" role="button" href="#" class= "text-navbar">Help</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>  <!--Chiudo la definizione della nostra navbar -->
```

posto il codice javascript che ho inserito!

```
<!--javascript code -->
<script language="javascript"> 
    function lightText() {                               //funzione che memorizza il testo selezionato
        var testoevidenziato= window.getSelection();
        alert (testoevidenziato.toString());
    }

    function togliModale(){                             //rimuove l'attributo data-dismiss
        $('#login').removeAttr('data-dismiss')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Show your JavaScript please.

Comment: all functions or lightText() and togliModale() only?

Comment: Let's start with `lightText()` and `togliModale()` :)

Comment: Can you produce a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where your problem is shown?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qrpda6z4/1/  if you reduce the ui and press the button on navbar, menu opens but doesn't close!

Comment: I see what you mean, but your fiddle is way too big to really find the culprit. Can you reduce the code greatly so that it isn't like looking for a needle in a haystack?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qrpda6z4/3/ this is the best I can do!

Comment: Found it, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

You've included bootstrap twice. If you remove one of the includes it works. Also, you've included several versions of jquery several times. You really shouldn't do this, because this can cause major issues!

In the head of your HTML, you have the following includes to jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

And in your body, you have the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Ideally, you should remove the includes in your head and only use includes at the bottom 
of your body. Ultimately, you want this to be as low in the body as possible:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

I've updated your **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrpda6z4/4/)** with these changes and you can see it now works.